# How to control the enemy in Tower Defense using Sprite Kit?

Tags: sprite-kit, game-physics, gamekit

I am new to IOS development. I want to make a Tower Defense game.

So here are some problems I have:

1. If I create a method to add enemies in an array, how do I know which enemy walking at the front? I want my towers always hit the front one.
2. I want to create a AOE(area of effect) damage, how to detect all the enemies that standing on a certain area?
3. Maybe like question 2, I want a ambient effect too, how to detect which enemy is near the enemy that got hit?

All answers will be appreciated!Thanks!

Comment: Please ask this question after you have gone through the features available in Sprite Kit.

Comment: Try asking a more specific question instead of multiple ones which are very broad in scope.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I will bring more details when I put it in code.